# formatting decimals to display a set number of characters

Tags: notepad++

I have data that looks like

```
X.27125 Y-.27125 Z1.
```

numbers vary from + to - and different decimal amounts.
its for a hobby CNC machine so data needs to look like

```
X000.271250 Y-000.271250 Z001.000000
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in two steps:

**First, add 0's:**

Find what: `([A-Z]-?)(\d*)\.(\d*)`
Replace with: `${1}000$2.${3}000000`

Then click on `Replace all`

**Second step, remove superfluous 0's:**

Find what: `0*(\d{3}\.\d{6})0*`
Replace with: `$1`

Then click on `Replace all`